# Import specific data from excel to datagrid vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to import the specific data from excel to datagrid and able to import the all excel data into datagrid using the below query

> Select *from [Allinone$]

also below query also working file

> Select status from [Allinone$]

But below query not working

> Select part.desc from [Allinone$]

And my code is below

```
Try
         Dim filename As String
         Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
         ofd.Title = "Please select the excel which you want to import"
         If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
             filename = ofd.FileName
             Dim strin As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & filename & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
             Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strin)
             If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                 con.Open()
                 Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
                 command.CommandText = "Select status from [Allinone$]"
                 command.Connection = con
                 Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
                 adapter.SelectCommand = command
                 Dim dt As New DataSet
                 adapter.Fill(dt, "AllTickets")
                 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
             End If
         Else
             MsgBox("Havn't selected the file,Form Gonna end now")
             Exit Sub
         End If
 Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.ToString)
 End Try
```

I hope there might be problem with .(dot) in header .. Is there any way to fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `part` and what is `desc`?

If the header of your column is `part.desc` then you should enclose it in square brackets, since it contains a special character.

Try this:

`Select [part#desc] from [Allinone$]`

**EDIT :** For some reason excel doesn't like dots in header when binding with OLEDB. Replace dots with # in your query.

Comment: Yes part.desc is header of the column .. i tried the above code but its not working ..throws the below error "invalid bracketing of the name '[part.desc]'

Comment: Can you attach your excel file here? It may not have all the data, just all the column headers and a few rows of data.